# Android SQLiteDatabase: Reading one column

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a one row database just for saving app data. My goal is to read one column (one value) from it.

This query returns all the columns in a Cursor:

```
public Cursor readAll() {
       return getReadableDatabase().query(tableName, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
```

It returns a Cursor with one row in it, just perfect. However, I don't want to read all columns at once, because it's slow as I have blob's in db too.
Instead, I'd like to read just one column at a time, separately. For example, for a column called "TEXT" it would be this:

```
public Cursor readText() {
      String[] projection = new String[]{"TEXT"};
      return getReadableDatabase().query(tableName, projection, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
```

However, this won't work, as I get back a Cursor with zero rows.

So, how to read a specific column from SQLiteBatabase in Android?

Comment: You can consider using SharedPreferences here if u are not storing any binary data in db. This is will be fast and easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Cursor readText() {
      return getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT colName FROM myTable", new String[] {});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax seems to be correct. Check please that you use right name of the column. Showing the table generation code and actual query code could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one also

```
public Cursor readText() {
  return getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT column_name FROM table_name", null);
}
```